# Codeigniter URI get confused because of hashed_password

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, encryption, segment

So what i did is an email verification function which stores my email in uri upon redirection from gmail to localhost the problem is that the email is encrypted and sometimes it does generate a result of "/" which confuses the uri segment and divides the encrypted email in segment 4 and 5.

Sample Uri with encryption:

```
http://yourdomain.com/system/index.php/controller/method/$2y$10$exTPJiuAiDRQzuiPV/AcW.YnYovq4n1ETbMdtOabHoWQ.yM9ePmPy
```

See the PV ' / ' AcW this divides the uri and i will be having problem in storing this as:

```
$email = $this->uri->segment(4);
```

i did try storing like this:

```
$email = $this->uri->segment(4) && $this->uri->segment(5);
```

but still gives me a boolean of false.

Comment: What are the outputs of segment 4 and 5 individually?

Comment: Change your encryption method to remove "/". Of course a slash will confuse the framework..

Comment: @VincentDecaux what encryption do i need to use so that it wont give a random "/" in syntax?

Comment: What encryption do you use now ? or just use a `str_replace('/', '.', $hash)` if you can

Comment: You don't have `$this->uri->segment(4)` and `$this->uri->segment(5)`. Instead you have `$this->uri->segment(3)` and `$this->uri->segment(4)`. Uri segments are counted after `index.php`.

Comment: i would not put password in url

Comment: Why are you doing it this way? Most Auth systems store a forgotten password code in the database and submit that hash to the user via uri so like localhost.com/forgotpass/hash. Then on hash you just match the row with that specific has with the user. Simple easy.

Comment: not familiar with hashing. so i have confused hashing password API and url.. anyways what can i use to hash data in url?

Comment: not familiar with hashing. so i have confused hashing password API and url.. anyways what can i use to hash data in url?

Answer (score 1):

isn't the way to go something like this:

your Link:

```
http://yourdomain.com/system/index.php/controller/method/?hash=<?=urlencode('$2y$10$exTPJiuAiDRQzuiPV/AcW.YnYovq4n1ETbMdtOabHoWQ.yM9ePmPy'); ?>
```

and in your controller/method you access it by

```
$strHash = $this->input->get('hash');
```